# elasticsearch scoring muliple using nested function_scores

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find the right approach for nested scoring functions.

DATA:

```
PUT test

PUT test/test/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "driver_id": {
         "type": "integer"
      },
      "driver_name": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "cities": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
            "city_id": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "used": {
               "type": "float"
            }
         }
      },
      "cars": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
            "car_id": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "used": {
               "type": "float"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


PUT test/test/1
{
  "id":1,
  "driver_name":"Lady Smith",
  "cars":[{"car_id":1,"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.5},{"car_id":2,"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.5}],
  "city":[{"city_id":3,"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},{"city_id":4,"name":"New York","used":0.2}]
}
PUT test/test/2
{
  "id":2,
  "driver_name":"John Smith",
  "cars":[{"car_id":1,"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.3},{"car_id":2,"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.3}],
  "city":[{"city_id":3,"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},{"city_id":4,"name":"New York","used":0.2}]
}
PUT test/test/3
{
  "id":3,
  "driver_name":"Will Smith",
  "cars":[{"car_id":1,"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.1}],
  "city":[{"city_id":3,"name":"New York","used":0.2}]
}
PUT test/test/4
{
  "id":4,
  "driver_name":"Ash Smith",
  "cars":[],
  "city":[]
}
```

To put it simply, given the data, I would like to get the best fit to the query of the driver that drives a Ford **AND** a Corolla in Tel Aviv.

Or, translated *loosly* to SQL:

```
SELECT driver_id,
   cr.cars_score * ct.city_score  AS driver_score
FROM drivers drv 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(used) / 2 as cars_score 
           FROM car_usage 
           WHERE car_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY driver_id) AS cr 
  ON (cr.driver_id = drv.driver_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(used) / 1 as city_score 
           FROM city_usage 
           WHERE city_id IN (3) GROUP BY driver_id) AS ct 
  ON (ct.driver_id = drv.driver_id)
```

Tried the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "disable_coord": true,
      "must": [
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "disable_coord": true,
              "must": [{
                  "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "cars",
                        "query": {
                          "function_score": {
                            "filter": {
                              "term": {
                                "cars.car_id": 1
                              }
                            },
                            "boost_mode": "replace",
                            "score_mode": "sum",
                            "functions": [
                              {
                                "field_value_factor": {
                                  "field": "cars.used",
                                  "factor":0.5,
                                  "missing": 0
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }, {
                  "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "cars",
                        "query": {
                          "function_score": {
                            "filter": {
                              "term": {
                                "cars.car_id": 2
                              }
                            },
                            "boost_mode": "replace",
                            "score_mode": "sum",
                            "functions": [
                              {
                                "field_value_factor": {
                                  "field": "cars.used",
                                  "factor":0.5,
                                  "missing": 0
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cities",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cities.city_id": 3
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "multiply",
                    "boost_mode": "replace",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cities.used",
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which gave me weird results.

then tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cars",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cars.car_id": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "boost_mode":"replace",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cars.used",
                          "factor":0.5,
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cars",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cars.car_id": 2
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "boost_mode":"replace",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cars.used",
                          "factor":0.5,
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cities",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cities.city_id": 3
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode":"multiply",
                    "boost_mode":"replace",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cities.used",
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

which was closer, but seemed to just sum all scores.

A friend of mine suggested flatting the entire JSON, and losing the nested objects (making them properties) but I'm unsure as to whether that will make it easier to query the data.

### UPDATE 1

another failed attempt :

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cars",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cars.car_id": 1
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cars.used",
                          "factor": 0.5,
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cars",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cars.car_id": 2
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cars.used",
                          "factor": 0.5,
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "cities",
                "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "cities.city_id": 3
                      }
                    },
                    "score_mode": "multiply",
                    "functions": [
                      {
                        "field_value_factor": {
                          "field": "cities.used",
                          "missing": 0
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Following my alternative method of flattening the fields and losing the nested filters, I ended with the following:

```
PUT test2

PUT test2/test2/1
{
  "id":1,
  "driver_name":"Lady Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.5},
  "cars_2":{"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.5},
  "cities_3":{"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/2
{
  "id":2,
  "driver_name":"John Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.3},
  "cars_2":{"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.3},
  "cities_3":{"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/3
{
  "id":3,
  "driver_name":"Will Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.1},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/4
{
  "id":4,
  "driver_name":"Ash Smith",
}

post test2/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "name": "red pepper"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "words",
                  "query": {
                     "function_score": {
                        "functions": [
                           {
                              "field_value_factor": {
                                "field" : "words.weight",
                                "missing": 0
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "query": {
                           "match": {
                              "words.text": "red pepper"
                           }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "boost_mode": "replace"
                     }
                  },
                  "score_mode": "total"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}

GET test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[{
            "exists":{"field":"cars_1"}
          },{
            "exists":{"field":"cars_2"}
        },{
          "exists":{"field":"cities_3"}
        }]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [{
        "script_score": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "(doc['cars_1.used'].value + doc['cars_2.used'].value) / 2 * doc['cities_3.used'].value"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not sure of the performance hit of the inline script. feels like I'm missing a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference of people who visit this post, 
I ended up changing my data model, and using [script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) (`lang:"painless"` in 5.0.0)

**Warning**: this method, although did fit my need, had an impact on performance, eyeballing estimate would be a hit of around 3-5 fold slower response time.

For now, it's good enough for me.

PUT test2

```
PUT test2/test2/1
{
  "id":1,
  "driver_name":"Lady Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.5},
  "cars_2":{"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.5},
  "cities_3":{"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/2
{
  "id":2,
  "driver_name":"John Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.3},
  "cars_2":{"brand":"Toyota Corola","used":0.3},
  "cities_3":{"name":"Tel Aviv","used":0.8},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/3
{
  "id":3,
  "driver_name":"Will Smith",
  "cars_1":{"brand":"Ford Focus","used":0.1},
  "cities_4":{"name":"New York","used":0.2}
}
PUT test2/test2/4
{
  "id":4,
  "driver_name":"Ash Smith",
}

post test2/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "name": "red pepper"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "words",
                  "query": {
                     "function_score": {
                        "functions": [
                           {
                              "field_value_factor": {
                                "field" : "words.weight",
                                "missing": 0
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "query": {
                           "match": {
                              "words.text": "red pepper"
                           }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "boost_mode": "replace"
                     }
                  },
                  "score_mode": "total"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}

GET test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[{
            "exists":{"field":"cars_1"}
          },{
            "exists":{"field":"cars_2"}
        },{
          "exists":{"field":"cities_3"}
        }]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [{
        "script_score": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "(doc['cars_1.used'].value + doc['cars_2.used'].value) / 2 * doc['cities_3.used'].value"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without flattening?